# How to change resource path dynamically based on the tenant(we are determining tenant based on host name)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant

I'm trying to set up multi-tenancy with different set of resource files for each tenant separated in different folders. Where should I set the resource path to pick the folder based on tenant(By the way I'm identifying tenant based on hostname)?

Here is the folder structure I'm having -

[image: Folder Structure]

As of Now I hardcoded the value to Tenant1 in ConfigureServices section of startup.cs as shown below

```cs
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/Tenant1");
```

Where can I reset this path based on the Host name and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own `IStringLocalizerFactory` which should creates `IStringLocalizer` based on the current tenant. Take a look at this to get an idea on how to write your custom factory [ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Localization/Localization/src/ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.cs)